# How do you define a function that will print a string with dashes in between characters in python?

Tags: python, string, function

I want to define a function (`print_with_dashes`) so that it will print the string `x` with dashes inserted between characters. In this example it would ideally print`h-e-l-l-o`

```
def print_with_dashes(x):
    print (x)

print_with_dashes ('hello')
```

Comment: `print('-'.join(x))`

Comment: So you've tried... what, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function.

```
def print_with_dashes(x):
    print '-'.join(x)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print_with_dashes('hello')
h-e-l-l-o
>>>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on your answer